# Qual a diferença entre anotação no método e anotação no atributo

Tags: java, hibernate, annotation

Galera, comecei a aprender e utilizar o `hibernate` recentemente, e ao procurar por respostas de minhas dúvidas referente à anotações já me deparei com seguintes ocasiões:

1ª) O atributo possui a anotação

```
@Column
private String descricao;

public String getDescricao(){
   return descricao;
}
```

2ª) A anotação é colocada no `get/set` do atributo

```
private String descricao;

@Column
public String getDescricao(){
   return descricao;
}
```

Eu estou usando a primeira opção sem um motivo específico. Mas bateu a dúvida: qual a diferença delas e qual é melhor (*recomendável*) utilizar?

Comment: Segue o link do SOen com sua dúvida, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6084701

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de existirem discussões a ***recomendação é utilizar a anotação diretamente no atributo***, exatamente como você está fazendo. 
A intenção do [ORM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional), no caso [hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/), é persistir o estado do objeto, sendo assim os ***atributos*** são a representação de ***estado*** do objeto.
A intenção de mapear um método assessor é questionada pelo fato de que **raramente** há legitimidade em modificar estado de um objeto diretamente ao obtê-lo. 
Por exemplo:

```
@Column
public String getUnidadeFederativa(){
   uf = (uf == null ? "UF não informada" : uf)
   return uf;
}
```

O bloco acima pode até fazer sentido para um uso local especifico, mas excede as fronteiras do [encapsulamento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamento) de um registro originado de um [SGBD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados), no qual consistência é obrigatória para esse contexto, o exemplo acima em questão não teria *constraint* no banco de dados com a tabela de UF, ou seja, o [encapsulamento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamento) da informação foi afetado arbitrariamente por um método assessor.

> Então porque existe a possibilidade de mapear um método assessor?

Existem algumas situações especificas que podem ser legítimas, é relativo, mas uma delas é seria ao necessitar mapear informações em subclasses de [Entity Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/collections/tutorial/Entity.html) de terceiros ([third-party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_software_component)) o qual não implementa nenhum tipo de [persistência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional), os atributos dessa entidade seriam privados e você teria que sobrescrever os assessores e então mapea-los com anotações.
 *(exemplo retirado de comentário de [Elnur Abdurrakhimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745188/elnur-abdurrakhimov) no [Stack Overflow US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access))*

Comment: Realmente é um excelente exemplo pra se utilizar o mapeamento nos métodos para acesso.