# Uso do '@' em variáveis

Tags: javascript, typescript, coffeescript

Vejo em algumas linguagens que compilam para javascript, como TypeScript e CoffeeScript, o uso do `@` em variáveis, como também, casos em que o mesmo não é utilizado. Por exemplo:

```
w = 10;
@v = 11;
```

No fim das contas, para que serve o `@` e qual a diferença entre usá-lo ou não?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No JavaScript, isso não quer dizer nada, nem mesmo é um identificador de variável válido (como `$` ou `_`).

No CoffeeScript, o `@` é a mesma coisa que `this`. Apenas [açúcar sintático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12964/18246).

No TypeScript, o `@` veio de herança do AtScript. Neste caso é um `decorator`, [igual aqueles do Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23628/101).

Answer (score 3):

São decoradores de funções e propriedades. Quando você usa um decorador adiciona ou altera a forma com a função ou propriedade trabalha.

Embora sejam parecidos com [anotações de Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76286/101) e [atributos de C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101), é se parece mesmo com o [decorador do Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23628/101).

Só está disponível a partir do EcmaScript 6.

[Proposta de implementação](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) dele que é onde vi algo mais canônico sobre ele.